# How to reduce the computational complexity of the algorithm for finding total prime numbers up to given numbers based on the algorithm I wrote?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, primes

I am trying the reduce the computational complexity of the algorithm I wrote below, where I try to find the all prime numbers up to given number, and return them in the array/list. Can you recommend me a way of reducing the computational complexity of that algorithm? For example, in the inner loop, instead of loop over "i", any way of looking number less than i?

Here is the code I have written

```
x = int(input("Enter a natural number ")) # Take the input
prime = []
for i in range(2,x+1):
  check = 0
  for j in range(2,i):
      if i % j == 0:
        check +=1
        break
  if check == 0:
      prime.append(i)
print("The numbers are: ", prime)
print("There are",len(prime), "numbers")
```

**Sample Input 1** : 20

**Sample Output 1** : Enter a natural number: 20

The numbers are:  [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]

There are 8 numbers

**Sample Input 2** : 50

**Sample Output 2** :Enter a natural number: 50

The numbers are:  [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]

There are 15 numbers

As you can see the complexity of the algorithm is **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**   since there are two nested loops.  It seems that we can get the better than **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

EDİT: Based on the "Sieve of Eratosthenes", using the square root(i) instead of i, reduce the computation. and in terms of results nothing changes. New complexity is O(n√n) which is O(n<sup>1.5</sup>).

Comment: Check out the Sieve of Eratosthenes or Euler's sieve for better complexities. However, two minor implementation improvements to your algorithm can be made by changing `for j in range(2, i):` to `for j in range(2, sqrt(i)):` since no number larger than the square root of i multiplied by another number larger than the square root of i can ever be i. And maybe instead of counting, just set check to 1 and break.

Comment: Two points.  First, except for 2, all primes are odd.  Second, after `check` has been incremented once you can flag that number as composite, there is no need to keep looking for other prime factors.

Comment: Beginner's mistake: if i is a factor of n, so is n/i, and one of i or n/i does not exceed √n. By testing divisors until √n, you reduce the complexity to O(n√n).

Comment: Yves Daoust. Yes. I must check my number theory knowledge. It works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code(I am not familiar with Python):

```
x = int(input("Enter a natural number ")) # Take the input
prime = []
for i in range(2,x+1):
  check = 0
  for j in prime:
      if i % j == 0:
        check +=1
        break
  if check == 0:
      prime.append(i)
print("The numbers are: ", prime)
print("There are",len(prime), "numbers")
```

Comment: There is no need to continue the search when j²>i.